# django - allow user to set something in database

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, model

I want to let user change language of a site by click on a country flag.

In my models.py file i have:

```
class RegularUser(models.Model):
    (...)
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null=True, blank=True, choices=[(a, _(b)) for (a,b) in settings.LANGUAGES], verbose_name=_("Language"))
```

I also made there a function:

```
def set_language(self, new_lang):
    lllang = self.language
    lllang = new_lang
```

In my html file i have:

```
function setLang(lang){
  language = document.getElementById("language")
  lang_form = document.getElementById("language_form")
  language.value= lang
  lang_form.submit()          
  {{request.user.get_profile.set_language(lang) }}                      
}
```

This function in setted to some button as "onclick".
This should do two thing:
1. Change immediately the language (it's done)
2. Change uset language in the database, so next time when we will log in - it will be as we set it now (it doesn't work :( )
I'm getting an error such:

```
   TemplateSyntaxError at /

   Could not parse the remainder: '("lang")' from 'request.user.get_profile.set_language("lang")'
```

Just to tell - if I'll put :

```
   {{request.user.get_profile.get_language}}
```

Then I'm getting code of my language, so it's fine.
get_language function from models.py:

```
def get_language(self):
    if self.language:
        return self.language
    elif self.location and self.location.country:
        return self.location.country.iso.lower()[:2]
    else:
        return None
```

Umm ... any help? 
Am I just giving the "lang" in a wrong way, or I don't get something in Django?

Answer (score 1):

In a Django template, you cannot call a Python function with parameters. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#variables . That's why you get no error message when you write `{{request.user.get_profile.get_language}}` (actually, your function is called without parameters, and the resulting exception is swallowed by Django).

Also, you cannot use the `lang` parameter, which is a client-side JavaScript function parameter, in a Python function on the server side. Try calling the function using AJAX - you'll need to add another view function for this, and I strongly suggest you don't use bare JavaScript, but a library like jQuery.

For your actual problem (letting the user set his preferred language), there's already [a function for that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) in [Django's internationalization package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/).